# How can I get TeXShop to work again

Tags: texshop

I had to wipe and restore my Macbook Pro after an OS upgrade always froze on sign-in. I formatted my drive and restored everything with a recent Time Machine backup. Then, running TeXShop, the console window gave a diagnostic (I think about some file missing) when I tried to work with existing LaTeX files.

I deleted the whole Tex Folder and downloaded TeXShop. Now it will open the Tex and Pdf files but the console window opens and does nothing when I hit CMND-T. I created a TEX folder and put it in there. No change.

Someone told me I needed MacTeX in my TEX folder so I looked for a download but the links do nothing, despite the page saying "downloading". How do I get TeXShop back?

Comment: I would suggest you consider reinstalling a fresh TeXLive 2020 from `https://www.tug.org/mactex/`.  If you don't want to reainstall the entire distribution you can try just reinstalling TeXShop from `https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried your MacTex link and clicked the download. I was unable to find it, as before, until I viewed the download folder as a list by name. I already have TeXShop 4.44 so I'm good with that.  All is working now. Thanks